# Show one .png image over another .jpg image

Tags: png, image, jpeg

I have the following code:

```
<img style="background: url(./image/data/logo.png) no-repeat top right" src="./image/data/picture.jpg" />
```

As it is now, it shows the logo.png under the picture.jpg image. How can I make it to be shown above the .jpg image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use 2 images to do that. The img must be with position absolute (The one that you want to be over the other).
 Don't forget that the container must have position:relative in order to contain the absoluted png.
Here is the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jNpaH/

The html tags:

> <div class="image">
>       <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7a/Basketball.png"
>   class="png-over" />
>       <img  src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/Papua_New_Guinea_map.png"
>   /> </div>

The styles:

```
.image{position:relative}
.png-over{position:absolute; top:0; left:0}
```

---

The problem with that technique is that your code becomes spammed with the image tags.
One way of solving it with jQuery is to find each div container with the class 'images' and prepend to each one the image tag.
Here is the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/jNpaH/2/

Comment: I simplified the code, and now has two images, so is there any way to add something to that code, so it will force the logo.png image to be shown over the picture.jpg? Or some replacement for the "background" text, like "foreground" or something?

Comment: Impossible, background images aren't supposed to be over their elements.

Comment: That in the case that the png image is smaller than the jpg.
But if the background size is bigger than the image, yes it can be under the image. That works well in the case that you want to make the background work as a border.
Here is the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/jNpaH/5/

Comment: Something like that, but I need it reversed, i.e. the basketball should be the main image, and the background should be the logo.png, because the basketball picture are actually different pictures, and I can't put that within the .css file, and I need the logo.png (in your case the background) to be over all of them.

Comment: Sorry I could not find a way. You said that you can't put that within the .css file. Does it mean that you can't access it? Because there are other ways to set the styles and achieve the same result. Also you can always use jQuery.

Comment: I can access it, but I want it as simple as possible (if possible) :) Thanks anyway, will take a look at your suggestions.

Comment: Just to notify you that I managed to get it work with this answer ;) Thanks again buddy.

Comment: Nice!, and don't forget that it is a good practice to separate: content(html tags) from styles(css) and behaviours(js). It means that it's better not to write inline styles inside the tags. Better do it in your stylesheet using classes. :)

Comment: Hey buddy, any chance helping me out with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896355/align-an-image-in-the-middle-of-td-td Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code I assume that you prefer to have a short html code. But it is impossible to have an image_tag with a background covering it.
The cleanest way is to use jQuery:
This is the final code:
http://jsfiddle.net/QyMkh/

First put a div that will contain all your images. The div must have a class, the images don't require it necessarily.

```
<div class="image">
     <img  src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/Papua_New_Guinea_map.png" />
     <img  src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/Papua_New_Guinea_map.png" />
     <img  src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/Papua_New_Guinea_map.png" /> 
</div>
```

Then add this jQuery block in the html before the closing </body>:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // store in a variable the url of the image that will be used as background
    var url = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7a/Basketball.png';

    // select every image_tag that is children of the div with the class 'image'
    jQuery('.image img').each(function() { 
        // every child image will be wrapped inside generated divs with a class 'img-wrap'
        $(this).wrap('<div class="img-wrap"></div>'); 
    });

    // After the images are wrapped, insert the image tag that will work as background, note that instead of using the source I'm using the variable that stores it.
    $('<img src="' + url + '" class="logo" />').prependTo('.img-wrap');
</script>
```

Finally add those style declarations to get the desired effect.

```
<style type="text/css">
.img-wrap{position:relative}
.img-wrap img.logo{position:absolute; top:0; left:0}
</style>
```

This code will keep your html documents with no unnecesary markup when you try to edit next time.
An advantage of using an image_tag as a background, is that with css you can resize its width and height. Try adding this new rule of stylesheet:

```
.img-wrap img.logo { height: 170px; left: 75px; position: absolute; top: 50px; width: 170px}
```

To end this, if you want more flexibility, for example you don't want the image_tags be container in a div, do this actions: replace this line of the jQuery block:

```
jQuery('.image img').each(function() {
```

with this

```
jQuery('.image').each(function() {
```

and add a class="image" to each

```
<img class="image">
```