# Align an image in the middle of <td></td>

Tags: html, css, png, alignment

I have the following  code:

```
<td>
<img src="some_image_url.png" class="png" />
<img src="another_image_url.jpg" />
</td>
```

The .css for the **class="png"** is:

```
.png {
    position:absolute;
}
```

How can I make the Sold Out image to be shown in the middle, as the other image is aligned?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Here's the .css for the **td**:

```
.something td {
    padding: 7px;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: On what browsers did you run it ?

Comment: I managed to sort the things out, adding a DIV between the TD, so now it's ok ;) Thanks for your effort buddy. P.S. I was running it on IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it like this:

```
td
{
  position: relative; /* if it's IE */
  /* position: fixed;  if it's mozila */
}
    .png , .jpg
    {
        position:absolute;
        left:50%;
        top:50%;
    }
    .png
        {
            margin-top: <put here half of the height of png>
            margin-left: <put here half of the width of png>
        }
```

add a class jpg to the jpg image

**UPDATE:** I edited it again, this works for me ...
make sure that your td is big enough

Comment: Nope, not working, already tried that :( It makes it even closer to the left border...

Comment: But are they centered ? try to remove the left:50%; and top:50%;

Comment: In my code, if I change the position:absolute; to position:relative; it alignes both images in the center, but now the .png is not over the .jpg, they are side by side...

Comment: Nothing happens :) Very strange, I have no idea why the .png image is not aligning in the middle as the other .jpg image does...

Comment: Still nothing, even with your edit, I need .png to be absolute, and .jpg to be relative, othervise the .png won't be over the .jpg...

Answer (score 0):

Set the table's text-align to center

Comment: It's already set, as you can see from the other image that is already aligned in the middle...

Answer (score 0):

sorry for not answering earlier, I have a solution:
(I don't have enought time, later I'll improve my answer)

The absoluted images aren't in the same flow as the default inline images, but you still can use 'text-align:center'

Just do the opposite, instead of putting the display absolute to the class="png", give it position:relative...
And now give position absolute to the img of the bottom:

```
<style type="text/css">    
.png {position:relative; z-index:10}
.bottom {position:absolute; z-index:0; left:0; top:0 }
</style>

<table>
<tr>
   <td style=" text-align:center">
     <img src="some_image_url.png" class="png" />
     <img src="another_image_url.jpg" class="bottom" />
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This way you'll have an automatic centered image on the top of another.
Don't forget that if you use position:absolute; you MUST set a top or bottom; or a left or right. In browsers like IE if you don't specify at least top with left, it will render in the IE way (broken).

(in my browser it is working I don't know why the fiddle doesn't show it the way I want, please test it and tell me if it is okay)

By the way, adding a div as you did is the best solution IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Set the float property of the image to

```
float: right;
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally `img`-tags are treated as `inline`-elements. Set it to `inline-block` and than you can change the line position behavior.

In your case that would look something like this:

```
.png {   
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This should solve this.
If not, than you might have a problem with the size of the image it self.

***Note:** I know it's a bit late and you might not need this anymore (very sure you don't) but as allways... some people come across this article and may need this information!*